# How to make a function run on the current page when the browser navigates backwards?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, navigation

BACKGROUND: To transition between pages on my site, I'm using a white opaque overlay layer which faded in/out. For example, when you click on a link, a script prevents default, fades the invisible white overlay from hidden to visible (making the screen completely white), then directs the browser to follow the original link. The destination page is initially also completely white because the overlay layer is visible by default. Once the destination page has loaded, a script tells it to fadeout, revealing the page beneath.

PROBLEM: by using the "onpageshow" tag within the "body" tag, I got the fade-from-white-to-clear effect to work when the user clicks the browser's backward navigation button. But I can't get the "onpagehide" tag to work they way I'd like--the browser just jumps straight to white (without the gradual fade to white effect) when the user clicks the browser's backward navigation button.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

function curtainup(event) {
    if (event.persisted) {
       $(".curtain").delay(500).fadeOut(500); 
    } else {
       $(".curtain").delay(500).fadeOut(500); 
    }}

</script>

<script>

function curtaindown(event) {
    if (event.persisted) {
        $(".curtain").fadeIn(500); 
    } }
</script>

<style>
    body {background-image: url('http://podcollective.com/assets/phong/world.patterns/egypt-V1/EGYPT-D-PATTERN.png');}

div#smalltextbox {
    z-index:5;
    position:relative;
    background:#7f7f7f;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    max-height:350px;
    max-width:1000px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right:30px;
    padding-bottom:40px;
    padding-left:30px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    left:320px;
    float:left;
    transform-origin: 0px 0px;
}

div.curtain {
    background:#FFFFFF;
    position:fixed;
    width:7000px;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1010;
}

</style>
</head>

<body onpageshow="curtainup(event)" onpagehide="curtaindown(event)">

    <div class="curtain"></div>

    <div id="smalltextbox"><p>Lorem ipsum omet orem ipsum omet orem ipsum omet orem ipsum omet orem ipsum omet orem ipsum omet orem orem...</p></div>

</body>
```

Comment: you might be able to use onunload

Comment: This is a common issue since browsers display the cached version of the page when hitting the "back" button.  Typically, this is where JavaScript depending on certain page loading events will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow your code logic, you would need to:

1. Intercept the "back button clicked" event.
2. Do the "fade-to-white" transition
3. Go back in history
4. etc...

The problem?
There's no such thing as "back button clicked" event. What I mean is, you can't intercept (or even know) when the user clicks the browser's back button.

**However...**

You can know when the user is about to leave the page with ["onbeforeunload" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload). In fact, that's how those annoying adds work (they pop up an alert when you're about to leave the page).

**...so...**

Instead of intercepting A tags (or buttons, or whatever) click events, you can use `onbeforeunload` event to trigger the fade-to-white transition.